# Why is value passed to method in optional hash a `nil`? (Ruby)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I've created a custom method and am trying to pass a value to it via an optional hash.

But the error message indicates to me that the method is not actually receiving the value I am passing, hence `nil`.

**View:**

```
<%= f.custom_form :height, { item: ‘weight’} %>
```

**Method:**

```
def custom_form(type, additional_items = {} )
  class_array = [‘form_control’]

  if additional_items
    class_array << additional_items[:item]
  end
end
```

**Error:**

> no implicit conversion of nil into String

But I'm not sure why this is occurring.

Apologies in advance if this is a newbie question.

Comment: please edit the quotes enclosing `form_control`. And can you show us the `class` where `custom_form` is declared?

Comment: Your example uses backticks instead of single quotes. Is this just a transcribing typo?

Comment: Note: your `custom_form` method returns either `nil` or an array, depending on the value passed for `additional_items`.

Comment: Are you really getting the error "no cimplicit conversion" error for the line, where you add the item to `class_array`?  Inspect the content of `additional_items`, to see, whether it really doesn't contain any element, or whether it contains other elements. Also, the logic is flawed. `if additional_items` will be always true, **except** if someone invokes the method with the second parameter **explicitly** set to `nil` or `false`.

Answer (score 1):

This line is ambiguous

```
<%= f.custom_form :height, { item: ‘weight’} %>
```

because it can be interpreted as one argument and a block

Try using explicit parentheses and you don't need the hash braces, they'll be assumed

```
<%= f.custom_form(:height, item: ‘weight’) %>
```

Comment: This isn't the case, at least in recent versions of Ruby. If this were the issue, OP would be getting a syntax error, not the exception he's seeing.